# Is there any additional canon confirmation that Wolfsbane potion loses potency unless taken very quickly?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

> “Fascinating,” said Snape, without looking at it. “You should drink that directly, Lupin.”

To me, this quote seems to indicate that - since there was no immediate danger of Lupin turning into werewolf right this moment - there was a another reason for Snape to insist on Lupin drinking ASAP.

The only logical reason seems to be if the potion is more potent when drank right after making. But it could also be Snape just being snippy.

Based on both Slytherince's and Anthony Grist's answers [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22822/is-there-canon-info-on-shelf-life-of-various-potions-in-harry-potter), it is 100% clear that the potion still works well enough for several days later.

**Is there any canon confirmation** (books/JKR info/Pottermore etc..) other than the PoA quote above of **whether the "drink that directly" was based on the fact that freshly brewed Wolfsbane potion is more potent - though not critically so - than non-fresh one?**

Comment: I personally can't think of anything, but maybe someone else can quote some evidence that would answer your question. I hope Pottermore will explore the Wolfsbane potion once they upload the *Prisoner of Azkaban* material (that could take years at the rate they're going).

Comment: I read that line with an implied "..before you forget/so you don't forget" at the end

Comment: An option not considered in the answers on the question you linked to is storing condition. Perhaps it is like cow milk, while vacuum it remains good, but after opening you have to drink it in a few days. Perhaps Snape has a way of conserving it for a longer amount of time (the quote in the question continues saying Snape made an entire cauldron of the potion, that would be wasted if he has not), but the bit in the cup is exposed to whatever is in the air and deteriorates thusly.

Comment: Until we get confirmation from the author, I think it is more likely related to what was revealed in later books about Snape and Lupin, and the animosity that instilled.